# Lineplot in Seaborn is "spikey"

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I am very new to seaborn and I am plotting sales over time for multiple genres of games. When I plot them together, it looks like seaborn is normalizing the data but I would like my y-axis to show the global sales value not normalized.
To avoid this, I tried setting the estimator in `sns.lineplot()` to `None`.

When I set the estimator to `=None` for my line-plot, my data suddenly gets all "spikey". I first thought that maybe my dataset had multiple values for each year or maybe some 0's in there for some reason, but this wasn't the case. For some genres there is no data for certain years, **but** it's getting "spikes" on genres that **have** data for every year.

Here it is without disabling estimator...

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
sns.lineplot(data=line_df,x='Year',y='Global_Sales',hue='Genre',ci=None)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Without Disabling]

And here is it when I disable it and the lines get "spikey"...

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
sns.lineplot(data=line_df,x='Year',y='Global_Sales',hue='Genre',ci=None, estimator=None)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot With Disabling]

Comment: The estimator takes the mean value within each `'Genre'` for each x value (`'Year'`). I'm not sure what you mean by "not normalized". Are you interested in seeing each datapoint, ie not averaged? That'll likely get pretty cluttered if so.

Comment: I guess I put too much information in my question. Really, I'd just like to know why my data is spikey like that. I've never used seaborn for line plots and it looks like I'm using it wrong. I was able to get the result I want from matplotlib on it's own but had to write a function (albeit small). The "spikes" are unexpected and I'm curious as to why is looks like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "spikiness"/sawtooth/shark fin pattern is because each data point is plotted when `estimator=None`. For each x-value, each data point is plotted along the vertical segments up to the max value. Then the line drops to the lowest value in the next x-value and then, again, goes up vertically hitting each data point until the maximum value for that x-value.  This is also mentioned in their [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/relational.html#emphasizing-continuity-with-line-plots).

This is more apparent if you plot the markers:

```
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers")
sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers", estimator=None, marker='o')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - just ran into the same.  Makes perfect sense, but was not immediately obvious.