# Seaborn lineplot not plotting means correctly

Tags: python, plot, graph, seaborn, line-plot

I am trying to plot data from a longform pandas dataframe. When I try to plot the data using seaborn lineplot I get a weird result. Instead of plotting the mean for each x (timepoint) value I get a spikey plot.

my code is:

```
import seaborn as sns

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,7))

sn = sns.lineplot(data=data_test,x="Timepoint",y="value",estimator = None,hue = 'Filename')

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,7))

sn = sns.lineplot(data=data_test,x="Timepoint",y="value",marker='o',estimator = 'mean')
```

Below are examples of the plots I get. The upper one is the individual values which are correct. The lower one should show the mean and confidence intervals of these values, but it is wrong.

Example plots from this code

[image]

#Here is an example dataset:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18LHD3dKfkXMvlqxp74uXQqVpHsGHIrtJUucxDMPFt4I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: From the given figure i can interpret that the plot is taking mean for some data points and plotting that's why you get a spike in the resulting graph. And i think you want a smooth mean plot which can be achieved by moving average function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with seaborn 0.11.0 and your test data. This is the output: https://imgur.com/a/V3Uu7ez

Comment: I can also not reproduce the issue with the current development version of seaboorn.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I updated my seaborn to the latest version but am still getting the same problem. I believe it is related to the following question because the 'spikiness' is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984668/lineplot-in-seaborn-is-spikey. However the replies here point to the problem being that the estimator is set to None, whereas my problem is when the estimator is set to 'mean'.

Comment: Any specific environment you run the code with (Spyder, Anaconda, Jupyter, Kaggle, you name it) that may change the seaborn behavior? Your confidence interval is also interrupted, so probably not related to the other problem (which I can reproduce in my IDE). How do you read the data file?

Comment: Just to finish off this thread in case anyone else encounters a similar problem, I solved the issue by rounding the "Timepoint" column which in my original dataset had 16 decimal places. It seems that lineplot cannot deal with such a large number of decimal places. When I copied across a subset of the data for this example it seems to have automatically truncated the numbers to only 5 decimal places which is probably why the commenters couldn't replicate the strange behaviour I got.